# Windows Vista Corrupt System File raschap.dll.mui

Tags: windows-vista, filesystem-corruption

After having troubles with the startup of my Windows Vista laptop (which now seems to be fixed).  I ran a `sfc /scannow` to check for any further problems.

After searching the log file I found it was unable to repair a the corrupted file `raschap.dll.mui`

I don't have a copy of the Vista Installation Disc, only a Recovery disk to reinstall the whole OS, which I don't to do for the sake of one file which has yet to show any impact.

Any suggestions for how to fix this?  I tied searching to download a copy of the file to just replace it manually, but couldn't find anything

I extracted parts of the log below which included the term 'corrupt' below:

```
2015-10-17 15:55:07, Info                  CSI    0000019f [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:58{29}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\en-US"\[l:30{15}]"raschap.dll.mui"; source file in store is also corrupted
....

2015-10-17 15:55:07, Info                  CSI    0000019f [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:58{29}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\en-US"\[l:30{15}]"raschap.dll.mui"; source file in store is also corrupted
....

2015-10-17 15:57:43, Info                  CSI    000001ce [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:42{21}]"Wdf01000Uninstall.mof" from store
2015-10-17 15:57:43, Info                  CSI    000001cf [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:24{12}]"Wdf01000.mof" from store
....

2015-10-17 15:59:50, Info                  CSI    0000020d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"raschap.dll.mui" of Microsoft-Windows-RasChap.Resources, Version = 6.0.6000.16386, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-10-17 15:59:50, Info                  CSI    0000020e [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:42{21}]"Wdf01000Uninstall.mof" from store
2015-10-17 15:59:50, Info                  CSI    0000020f [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:24{12}]"Wdf01000.mof" from store
....

2015-10-17 15:59:50, Info                  CSI    00000215 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:58{29}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\en-US"\[l:30{15}]"raschap.dll.mui"; source file in store is also corrupted
```

thanks

Comment: This cannot be solved without a Vista installation disk.  Of course given the file that is corrupt you don't need to fix it.  It is connected to the .Windows Foundation Language Pack, it isn't critical in most cases, if it is then you need to find a vista installation disk for the version of Vista you have or get it from a known good installation by hand.

Comment: @Ramhound Great!  Sounds like I've nothing to worry about.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: run the checksur tool: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821